# Linear transformation on eigenvalues within an eigenvalue decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

Suppose I have a diagonalizable real matrix $A$ with the right eigenvectors $X$ and diagonal eigenvalue matrix $\Lambda$ such that $$A = X \Lambda X^{-1}.$$ (In fact in my case $A$ is symmetric so $X^{-1} = X^T$). Suppose I also have a known matrix $B$ (in my base $B$ is real skew-symmetric), and I am interested in looking at properties of the matrix $$A_2 = X B \Lambda X^{-1}.$$ Is there anything I can say about $A_2$ related to $A$? I know it's not a well formed question, but since I'm not sure if there is any established theory on this, I tried googling but lacked the proper terminology to find anything meaningful.

Comment: It is not very likely you will get an answer, this is mostly because we cannot guess what you want. If you can, you should probably specify in what context you want to use this.

Comment: Yea I know it's vague, I was kind of hoping this sort of transformation / decomposition would have a name from which I could do some further reading. I'm trying to interpret the matrix $A_2$ in the context of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$, and I find that it is 'generated' by this $B$ matrix. What does this mean physically? The further away $B$ is from the identity matrix it seems I am taking $A_2$ away from $A$, but I don't really understand how, as opposed to an analytic matrix function such as $f(A) = X f(\Lambda) X^{-1}$ for which I could easily interpret the action of $f$.

Comment: Since $B \Lambda$ is no longer diagonal, you loose the properties of this operation.